# Using JavaScript To Change the HTML Contained In An External Script

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I have an element on my website that is hosted externally and referenced in a script on my page.

I want to automatically change the text within this content so that it always displays tomorrow's date.

Script for the widget:

```
<script src="//my.externalwidget.com/12345.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="async"></script>
```

HTML contained in external script:

```
<div id="changeHeaderOne">THIS SHOULD DISPLAY TOMORROW'S DATE</div>
```

My JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var dateParse = currentDate.toString();
var dayAbbr = dateParse.substr(0, 3);
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("changeHeaderTwo").innerHTML = "Tomorrow's date is " + dayAbbr + " " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
document.getElementById("changeHeaderOne").innerHTML = "Tomorrow's date is " + dayAbbr + " " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

I know my script is working because it runs properly on #changeHeaderTwo (located in DOM) but not on #changeHeaderOne (externally hosted and loaded using the script on top).

Any ideas how to make this apply to the externally loaded code as well?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `document.getElementByClass()` (which should really by [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)) when your div has an id. Use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) instead.

Comment: PZP Thanks for your response,

I am using the ID. I don't know why I put class in the question. I edited my question to reflect how it actually is right now (still not working).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You still have it wrong. It should be ``getElementById``, not ``getElementByID``. Capitalization matters :P

Comment: You are absolutely right, capitalization does matter! I have it capitalized correctly, I just have no idea how to type so I wrote the question wrong... again... (sorry!).

So, it is capitalized correctly but still not working. See above, I edited the question again to reflect the correct code this time (literally copy/pasted from my site).

Do you have any ideas why it may not be working?

Comment: And yes, there is a </script> tag at the end, its just not showing on stackoverflow for some reason

Comment: What order are you loading the scripts in? You need to make sure that the externally loaded one has already inserted ``#changeHeaderOne`` into the DOM before you can manipulate it. Since you are loading the external script asynchronously, it is quite probable that your code is just executing before the external script loads. Try removing the ``async`` attribute from the external script.

Comment: My script is loaded below the external script. I removed `async` attribute from the external script and still no change. I also modified my script to execute on page load (after the content in question was already visible) and it still only changed `#changeHeaderTwo`, which I saw happen. Is it possible that the company hosting the code (it's a header bar) would want me to only be able to edit the content manually from the back-end, and doesn't allow JS to modify it? If so, would there be a possible work-around? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Would you mind making a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) of your code?

Comment: It looks from viewing the page source that the code is never actually loaded fully into the page! I didn't know that was even possible. I created a work-around by just hosting all of the files locally myself. Thanks for all your help!